# Memcpy : Adding an int offset?

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

I was looking over some C++ code and I ran into this memcpy function.  I understand what memcpy does but they add an int to the source.  I tried looking up the source code for memcpy but I can't seem to understand what the adding is actually doing to the memcpy function.

```
memcpy(Destination, SourceData + intSize, SourceDataSize);
```

In other words, I want to know what SourceData + intSize is doing.  (I am trying to convert this to java.)

EDIT:

So here is my attempt at doing a memcpy function in java using a for loop...

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < SourceDataSize ; i ++ ) {
      Destination[i] = SourceData[i + 0x100];
}
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with memcpy, it's just very basic pointer arithmetic

Comment: How to convert from language A to completely unrelated language B: 1) understand what the original code is supposed to do; 2) understand how the original code does what it is supposed to do; 3) figure out how that can be done in language B; 4) write the code. The question seems to be missing steps #1 and #2. You'll have a hard time getting good answers.

Comment: @R.Martinho, one way of understanding what code is *supposed* to do is to figure out what it *does*. Thus, I think this question goes toward accomplishing step 1.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Really? because i'm pretty sure that i stated clearly that i DO NOT UNDERSTAND what it is doing.  Hence the question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the same thing as:

```
memcpy(&Destination[0], &SourceData[intSize], SourceDataSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

The add will change the address used for the source of the memory copy.

The amount the address changes will depend on the type of SourceData.

(See http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/68-pointers-arrays-and-pointer-arithmetic/)

It might be trying to copy a section of an array SourceData starting at offset intSize and of length SourceDataSize/sizeof(*SourceData).

EDIT

So, for example, if the array was of integers of size 4 bytes, then the equivalent java code would look like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < SourceDataSize/4 ; i ++ ) {
  Destination[i] = SourceData[i + intSize];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic pointer arithmetic. SourceData points to some data type, and adding n to it increases the address it's pointing to by n * sizeof(*SourceData).

For example, if SourceData is defined as:

```
uint32_t *SourceData;
```

and

```
sizeof(uint32_t) == 4
```

then adding 2 to SourceData would increase the address it holds by 8.

As an aside, if SourceData is defined as an array, then adding n to it is sometimes the same as accessing the nth element of the array. It's easy enough to see for n==0; when n==1, it's easy to see that you'll be accessing a memory address that's sizeof(*SourceData) bytes after the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 1):

SourceData + intSize is skipping intSize * sizeof(source data type) bytes at the beginning of SourceData. Maybe SourceDataSize is stored there or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent to `memcpy` in Java that you're probably going to get is [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29), since Java doesn't really have pointers in the same sense.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding doing this in Java:

Your loop

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < SourceDataSize ; i ++ ) {
      Destination[i] = SourceData[i + 0x100];
}
```

will always start copying data from `0x100` elements into SourceData; this may not be desired behavior. (For instance, when `i=0`, `Destination[0] = SourceData[0 + 0x100];` and so forth.)  This would be what you wanted if you never wanted to copy `SourceData[0]..SourceData[0xFF]`, but note that hard-coding this prevents it from being a drop-in replacement for memcpy.

The reason the `intSize` value is specified in the original code is likely because the first `intSize` elements are not part of the 'actual' data, and those bytes are used for bookkeeping somehow (like a record of what the total size of the buffer is).  `memcpy` itself doesn't 'see' the offset; it only knows the pointer it's starting with.  `SourceData + intSize` creates a pointer that points `intSize` bytes past `SourceData`.

But, **more importantly**, what you are doing is likely to be **extremely slow**.  `memcpy` is a *very* heavily optimized function that maps to carefully tuned assembly on most architectures, and replacing it with a simple loop-per-byte iteration will dramatically impact the performance characteristics of the code.  While what you are doing is **appropriate if you are trying to understand how memcpy and pointers work**, note that if you are attempting to port existing code to Java for actual use you will likely want to use a morally equivalent Java function like `java.util.Arrays.copyOf`.